# set the tbody id of a GridView

Tags: asp.net

wow, strongly typed item type values, but still no easy way of setting the thead and tbody information of a asp.net web controls.

I've used this to fix that issue:

```
grid.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader
```

in the pretender method, but how does one then assign and id to the corresponding tbody tag. I need to use JQuery to traverse through the tr elements, but not without first having this id set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try it without assigning `#id` to it...Same way you could traverse it like below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#GridView tbody").addClass('className');
});
```